# How can I call a macro with multiple arguments via the Visual Studio IDE?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, macros, envdte, visual-studio-macros

In Visual Studio 2010, if a macro has one argument, you can call it from the Command window, the Find box, or the Immediate window, by typing

```
>Foo bar
```

where `Foo` is the macro name and `bar` is a string argument.

But if the macro has two or more arguments, this doesn't work:

```
>Foo bar, baz
```

This just treats "bar, baz" as one value. This bug is recorded in Connect:

[command-window-accept-2-arguments](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653513)
[passing-multiple-parameters-to-a-macro-does-not-work-as-expected-based-on-the-documentation](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/346014)

Is there any other way to call a macro with multiple arguments, other than calling it programatically?